# How can I display the fields with "0" value in the table?

Tags: php, mysql

**In phpMyAdmin, my table called Uniforms:**

| Name | T-Shirt Size | T-Shirt Quantity | Pant Size | Pant Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | L | 2 | L | 2 |
| John | XXL | 1 | XXL | 1 |
| Linda | S | 2 |  | 0 |

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE Uniforms (
    name varchar(255),
    tshirt_size SET('XS','S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL') NOT NULL,
    tshirt_quantity INT(10) NOT NULL,
    pant_size SET('XS','S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL') NOT NULL,
    pant_quantity INT(10) NOT NULL
);
```

In the **process_myform.php:**

```
$completedFields = 0;

if($_POST['tshirt_size'] != NULL) { 
    $completedFields++; 
} 
if($_POST['pant_size'] != NULL) { 
    $completedFields++; 
}

if ($completedFields > 0) {
    $tshirt_size = $_POST['tshirt_size']; 
    $tshirt_quantity = $_POST['tshirt_quantity'];
    $pant_size = $_POST['pant_size']; 
    $pant_quantity = $_POST['pant_quantity'];
} else {
    $errors[] = "Choose at least one item";
}
```

**To fetch and display data:**

```
$sql = "SELECT tshirt_size, SUM(tshirt_quantity) AS TotalTshirts FROM Uniforms GROUP BY tshirt_size";
$q = $connect -> prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($q->rowCount() > 0) {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Tshirt</td>';

    foreach($result as $res) {
        echo '<td>'. htmlentities ($res->TotalTshirts) .'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

**My Desired output:**

| Uniform | XS | S | M | L | XL | XXL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T-Shirts | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Pants | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

**Actual Result:**
The problem - if I query to find out the total for each size, it doesn't display "0" if it's 0. Instead, I get:

| Uniform | XS | S | M | L | XL | XXL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T-Shirts | 2 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Pants | 0 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |

Comment: You should create a `sizes` table and have `'XS','S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL'` in there with and id for each. Then link shirts and pants by the id. Currently you have no way to select sizes that don't exist.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will make a table for sizes. I don't have an idea yet how to do the linking, but I'll try to do some research.

Comment: the linking you're referring to is called a JOIN

Answer (score -1):

You can use the conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT tshirt_size, sum(case when tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) AS TotalTshirts 
FROM Uniforms 
GROUP BY tshirt_size
```

This is an other option to get all the data using one single query using the conditional aggregation and `union all`:

```
SELECT 'T-Shirts' as Uniform,
  sum(case when tshirt_size='XS' and tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) as 'XS',
  sum(case when tshirt_size='S' and tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) as 'S',
  sum(case when tshirt_size='M' and tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) as 'M',
  sum(case when tshirt_size='L' and tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) as 'L',
  sum(case when tshirt_size='XL' and tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) as 'XL',
  sum(case when tshirt_size='XXL' and tshirt_quantity > 0 then tshirt_quantity else 0 end) as 'XXL'
FROM Uniforms
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pants' as Uniform,
  sum(case when pant_size='XS' and pant_quantity > 0 then pant_quantity else 0 end) as 'XS',
  sum(case when pant_size='S' and pant_quantity > 0 then pant_quantity else 0 end) as 'S',
  sum(case when pant_size='M' and pant_quantity > 0 then pant_quantity else 0 end) as 'M',
  sum(case when pant_size='L' and pant_quantity > 0 then pant_quantity else 0 end) as 'L',
  sum(case when pant_size='XL' and pant_quantity > 0 then pant_quantity else 0 end) as 'XL',
  sum(case when pant_size='XXL' and pant_quantity > 0 then pant_quantity else 0 end) as 'XXL'
FROM Uniforms
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qVwkKXV2)